# How to hide some compiled files from showing up in gerrit review

Tags: gerrit

I have a project where many files like package-lock and other compiled file pollute the to-review file list. I don't want move them out of git as they significantly reduce install and run time. Is there a way to tell Gerrit to not show these files?

Answer (score 0):

No, so far (Gerrit 3.2.3) there's no way to hide these files.

As you probably know, it's not a good idea to store binary files in Git so you could try to use the [Git LFS](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-lfs) feature of the [Gerrit lfs plugin](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/admin/repos/plugins/lfs)